# Dragonfly: How to set max image size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dragonfly-gem

How to set max image size and weight/height using Dragonfly? Max size will be different for different models, so i would like to set it in model lvl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post, http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2010/1/13/dragonfly, you can do it with the following, where 400 is the max

```
class Album
  validates_property :width, :of => :cover_image, :in => (0..400)
end
```

Comment: yeah, more about validation found at: http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.Models.html